# Accessing web based applications from the command line - Case360

Tags: web-applications, command-line

We have a tool in place (Case360) that is used for capturing images and data and managing the workflows and such to get the data where it needs to go.

I am approaching this from a configuration management perspective.  We manage the deployment of changes to our formal test environments.  The "deploy" process involves accessing the application (which is local, not hosted) via a browser and importing xml files.  When the application reads the xml it updates the various fields, queries, workflows, etc.

We are currently attempting to get this app automated on the deployment side but I can find no documentation anywhere on the web as to how to access this via the command line to put in our scheduling tool.

Looking for advice or experience to figure out a good place to start, from web searches and the company's web site ([OpenText](http://www.opentext.com/support)) there just doesn't seem to be any information out there.

Comment: What do you mean 'from the command line'? You can use `wget` or `curl` to make requests to specific pages if that's what you want to do. You could upload files to your website through an xml file with `curl` pretty easily. Your question to too broad, and doesn't seem to be programming related. Give us an example of some of your code that you've used previously for a similar task, or some code you already have written.

Comment: Command line tends to be what we use when we script changes in our scheduling/automation tool for other applications.  The application in this case is predominantly java, I guess I am looking for a place to start/guidance on how I can utilize the import command without going through the GUI.  Would this make more sense on SU?

Comment: Some applications have an API you can connect to and run commands, but I didn't see one for Case360. If you're using java, take a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/). You can make request to specific pages, and provide the necessary headers, and also upload an XML file.